# How to update div outside bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a page that calls a bootstrap modal window with external content.  The modal window consists of a form.  The form is using jquery validate and I'm trying to use an ajax submit handler.  The problem is that it doesn't seem I can access the main div I want to update from.  The modal window is using its own html page.  I want to update a div that was used to call the modal window, is something like this possible?

No code unless you want me to post to better clarify.  Hope what I want to do makes sense.

edit: [Main page is what I want to update from ajax call in modal]

```
[Main Page]
<div id='div-id-want-to-update-on-submit'></div>

<a href='/some-external-form' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#my-modal'>Launch Modal</a>

[Modal Window]
<div id="my-modal" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form action=/post-somewhere>
...
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
... some jquery  to validate and ajax call to another method.

    var request;
    request = $.ajax({
        url: '/post-method/returns-html',
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
     });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#div-id-want-to-update-on-submit').html(response);
    });
</script>
```

[edit2] - Ignore this, I made a stupid type in my update div.  no window.opener was needed as recommended below, the DOM is available from the main page.

Comment: Yeah, you better show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the opening document with `window.opener.document`

e.g.

```
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $(window.opener.document).find('#div-id-want-to-update-on-submit').html(response);
});
```

Comment: This is throwing an exception:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null

Comment: Are you testing it on a server, or just by file:// and is the external form on the same domain if so?

Comment: All contained on same server.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is because the request is inside a .validate submitHandler function.