# passing value from modal to main form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a contact script as follows:

```
    <?php
    Session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location:../index.php");
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link href="../libraries/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="../libraries/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libraries/css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="../libraries/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libraries/date/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libraries/date/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Get Organization ID
        function getOrganizationID(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getorganizationid.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
        // Auto Complete for Organization field
        $(function() {
            $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
                source: '../libraries/organization/search.php'
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //
        function chName(value) {
          var val_fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
          var val_lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
          var val_fullname = val_fname + ' ' + val_lname;
            document.getElementById('org').value = val_fullname;
        }
        // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div id="main">
    <form name="create" id="create" method="post" action="do_create.php">
        <table style="width:100%;font-weight:bold;">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" required>*</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input id="lname" name="lname" type="text"  onblur="chName(this.value)" required>*</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td><input name="phone" type="text" required>*</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input name="email" type="text" required>*</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Mobile Phone</td>
                <td><input name="mobile" type="text"></td>
                <td>Organization</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="skills" type="text" name="skills" value="" onblur="getOrganizationID(this.value);return false;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">+</button>
                    <div id="txtHint" style="width:1px;height:1px;">
                        <input id="organization_id" name="organization" type="hidden" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <input id="org1" type="hidden" name="ocname" value="<?php echo $hash;?>">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>


    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function chOrg(value) {
        var val_oname = document.getElementById('oname').value;
            document.getElementById('skills').value = val_oname;
        }
    </script>
            <form name="addorganization" id="addorganization" method="post" action="add_organization.php"  target="myIframe" onsubmit="chOrg(this.value)">
            <div id="headsum">
                <strong>Create Organization</strong>
                <input style="float:right;" name="add_organization" type="submit" value="SAVE">
            </div>
                <table style="width:100%;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Organization Name</td>
                        <td><input name="oname" type="text"  required>*</td>
                        <td>Contact Name</td>
                        <td><input id="org" type="text" name="org" value="" readonly>*
                        <input id="org1" type="hidden" name="ocname" value="<?php echo $hash;?>"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone</td>
                        <td><input name="ophone" type="text" required>*</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><input name="oemail" type="text" required>*</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <iframe style="display:none;" src="" name="myIframe" id="myIframe">
            </iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

when I click the button beside the organization filed, will appear a popup (modal) to add an organization.
organization contact name on the form is automatically populated with the name that fill in the main form.

What I want to ask here is:
how after the organization form stored, the name of the organization and hash on the main form will automatically be filled with the names and hashes saved from earlier organizational form, because of what I have tried has not succeeded

Comment: you forgot to close the body and html tag

Comment: @madalinivascu : don't have body and html tag, but anyway, thanks for reminder.

Comment: and also i found that i missing one id (id="oname"). 
:)

but, still, i need to clean this script since i'm really beginner in programming

Comment: oh, i can't edit my comment?

i also find similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554027/pass-data-to-parent-window-from-modal-using-bootstrap
i'll try to leran more from here

Answer (score 0):

Hello Take one hidden field in main form. so after submitting the form pass that value to the hidden field.

Hope it helps !!