# How to store, display and pass information between main window and modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I have a REST front end and are working with a person model {surname, firstname, date of birth etc}. The main page has a "Add Person" button which opens a modal for query based on name or drivers license.

The results of the query are combined and displayed in each row of a table in a second modal where the user can either select a person using a radio in the first column and click the button to add that person to the main page or click the button to "Create New Person".

[image]

Each person in the result set is added to the result table table like this:

```
$('#tablePersonResponse').append('<tr><td><input type="radio"
name="selectPersonRadio"></td><td>' +nameArray.filter(Boolean).join('/')+
'<p class="text-secondary">' +result.address.formattedAddress+ '</p></td></tr>');
```

Should I be sending the selected person back to the main window in individual fields or sending back just the UID and getting the main window to make query to the back end to get the rest of the information about the person model.

If individual fields are returned to the main window from the modal, then would I have to avoid combining the results of the initial query in each row?

Is it good design for the main page to only submit the UID in respect of the person model when sending data to the backend?

It is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554027/pass-data-to-parent-window-from-modal-using-bootstrap) but I am also asking about how to store the data in the results table.

Comment: I think you should move the data from the popup to the main page instead of a round trip to database again. Also it is better if you can manage this state and use it on both places.

Comment: @UsmanAfzal Thanks. That is part of the question how to manage the data between windows?